Cannot find module '@tanstack/react-query-devtools' or its corresponding type declarations
I have installed the latest version of @tanstack/react-query and @tanstack/react-query-devtools but when try to import ReactQueryDevtools from @tanstack/react-query-devtools, it gives the above error
Here is my package.json file
{
  "name": "intermediate-react",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.32.1",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^5.32.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "framer-motion": "^6.5.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}


Here is my main.tsx file
import React from "react";
import { ChakraProvider, ColorModeScript } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import "./index.css";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
import theme from "./theme.tsx";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode} />
      <App />
      <ReactQueryDevtools />
    </ChakraProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


I have tried to install the previous version of react-query-devtools but the problem persist

Have you tried to import the type declarations? Doesn't the error message give you the command to install them?

Perhaps the package was installed incorrectly, try (If you have NODE)

npm uninstall @tanstack/react-query-devtools
npm i @tanstack/react-query-devtools

Then import the devtools like this:
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools'
Wrap the rest of the components in
<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}> </QueryClientProvider>

In your case it should look like this
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
   {/* The rest of your application */}
   <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
 </QueryClientProvider>

